# How to make an object move with a velocity to a point, and from that point with other velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to move an object with a velocity to a point, and make it stop when he reached that point.

```
  void FixedUpdate()
    {
      if (transform.position.y == 0f) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0f);
      } //first change of the velocity

      if (transform.position.x == 0f){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
      }
    }//here i want to stop
.........................................................

public void MoveR()
    {
      rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, upSpeed);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your logic there. If you want to move an object to a specific position as you asked. There is a more simplified way of moving an object in Unity. See [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html).

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 myTarget;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveTo());
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveTo()
    {
        while (transform.position != myTarget)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, myTarget, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

            yield return null;
        }

    Debug.Log("We reached Target. Done!");
    yield return null;
    }
}
```

If you want, you can declare myTarget as a GameObject. In that case, you will need to create an empty gameObject or select one that already exist.