# How do I use a Coroutine (or any other method) to slide a sprite across the screen on click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I'm developing a 2D game in Unity, and I am stuck with a problem. I am trying to move a sprite from point A to point B when the user clicks. I have a Vector3 for both the starting point and the target.

I was able to get the desired change in position but only in one frame. I want the sprite to actually slide across, but I have been unable to. I tried using Coroutines but have not been successful.

```
IEnumerator CubeSlider(Vector3 start, Vector3 target)
    {
        while(start.x != target.x)
        {
            start.x += 0.1f;
            yield return null;
        }    
    }
```

I'm only taking x into account because there is no movement on the y axis. I also tried using:

`start = Vector3.MoveTowards(parameters here)`

but was not successfull.

I started and called this Coroutine on my "onMouseDown()" function of the script like so:

```
StartCoroutine(CubeSlider(square1.transform.position, p3));
```

I would expect that when the user makes a click, the sprite would smoothly move across from start to target. I'm not getting any compiler errors, it's simply not moving at all.

Comment: Well perhaps it doesnt move because you never applied start to the transform?

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry, I am new to this, what do you mean by applying the start to the transform?

Comment: you took a copy of the values from the transform position, but you never applied them back to the object

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is incorrect. You are just adding to that float value another float value. Instead, you need to use Vector2 or Vector3. You can use your approach and that is not going to have any errors, but that won't affect your gameObject. If you wanted to move an object like that, you needed to use Vector2 or Vector3 in your loop. Also, you will need a helper method because values between those 2 Vectors will never be exactly equal. Below is one example of your first approach.

```
start.position += new Vector3(2f, 0f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Since I see that you are passing arguments to your Coroutine, if you want to move a gameObject that doesn't have this script attached, pass its Transform Component. Of course, because this is an example I have placed everything in 1 Script. Below is an example of [Unity Method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html).

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 myTarget;
    public Transform myStart;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CubeSlider(myStart, myTarget));
    }

    IEnumerator CubeSlider(Transform start, Vector3 target)
    {
        while (start.position.x != target.x)
        {
            start.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(start.position, target, 2f * Time.deltaTime);

            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("I reached my target. Done!");
    }
}
```

If you are interested you may also want to see my other answer on this topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562726/how-to-make-an-object-move-with-a-velocity-to-a-point-and-from-that-point-with/55563675#55563675).